# How to set number of reducers based on input size

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, apache-pig

How can i set no.of reducers based on my input size to my mapreduce job.
I know it in hive and pig as flollows

```
hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer
pig.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer
```

I want similar job to do in my Map-Reduce job please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing which comes to my mind is to analyze input before submitting job and set number of reducers based on input size.

For example if you are using HDFS input source there is method called getContentSummary (http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#getContentSummary(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path)) which gives you back size of input.

After that you can use that information to calculate number of reducers. (Some logic which accommodate your needs) and then set that number using setNumReduceTasks.

For other data sources you should use similar approach.

Comment: Then 
FileSystemOBJ.getContentSummary(Path filePath).getLength()
will do my job?

Comment: you should use getSpaceConsumed() method to get actual size of files.